# Flutter: Display Error to User

Tags: flutter

I have a url_launcher that opens up an Email app a an onTap listener and would like to show an error if there is no email app installed on the device ? How can this be achieved using the Flutter framework ?

The _launchcaller() throws an exception when an email app does not exist, but I would like the error message (custom message) to be displayed to the user so they know what is going to on ?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Thank you"),
        ),
        body: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: animationController,
                  child: new Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    child: new Image.asset('assets/angry_face.png'),
                  ),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                    return new Transform.rotate(
                      angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
                      child: _widget,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                    'We are sorry for the inconvenience...',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                  new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 0.0)),
                  new Text(
                    'Please contact us to resolve this issue!',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding:
                    new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _launchcaller,
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.contact_phone,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 45.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    new GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _launchcaller,
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.email,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]));
  }

  _launchcaller() async {
    const url = 'mailto:enissl21@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body';

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless that isn't a choice, you can show a snackbar, like this.

You have a `Scaffold`, so add a key to it

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();


Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldkey,
    ...
```

Then throw error like this:

```
_launchcaller() async {
    const url = 'mailto:enissl21@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body';

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      scaffoldkey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: new Text('Error: ${url}'),
          duration: new Duration(seconds: 10),
        );
      );
      throw 'Could not launch $url'; // <-- you might wanna ignore/comment this part out
      // Or use a `print('Could not launch $url')` instead.
      print('Could not launch $url')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Solution does not work ? The SnackBar section gets marked as dead code !

Comment: @IssmeilB. Bring the scaffoldkey part up before the throw. `throw` returns, and thus any code below won't run. I've edited the answer. You might wanna use `print()` instead of `throw`

Comment: Did it differently and worked. Will try you answer again and if it works, I will mark it as a correct one.

Comment: Worked for me, but variable issues. _scaffoldKey was not camel-cased in the Scaffold widget and was missing the underscore in the else block,

Comment: It's unclear to me how _scaffoldkey gets communicated to scaffoldkey. I'm also a little puzzled by that semicolon after the parenthesis closing the SnackBar call.  I'm also puzzled that this is the best answer on SO for the question of how to display errors to users in Flutter. Surely there's a best practices approach with support in the framework? No?

Answer (score 4):

Solution without scaffoldKey:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    content: Text('error message'),
  )
)
```

This shows a white area at the bottom of the screen which stays for 5 seconds (specified `duration`) and then disappears again:

[image]

To add nice styling to the message I found [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWXC0DHIIfQ) quite helpful.

Comment: Suppose you don't have access to context? Suppose you are deep into your app and need to display a message?  It seems a key is needed, but the previous answer doesn't explain how the key is communicated to ScaffoldMessenger. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

Per one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833689/flutter-no-scaffoldmessenger-widget-found) by [edalvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10942128/edalvb) an excellent solution seems to be to create a global snackbar class like this:

```
class SnackbarGlobal {
  static GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> key =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  static void show(String message) {
    key.currentState!
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }
}
```

You get the key into your Material App at the top level

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: SnackbarGlobal.key,
      routes: routes,
      initialRoute: 'pageOne',
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can just call `SnackbarGlobal.show('message')` from wherever you want and ScaffoldMessenger figures out what Scaffold to use and pops up your message.