# Flutter : No ScaffoldMessenger widget found

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a snackbar on the click of a button in flutter, but getting exception that No `ScaffoldMessenger` widget found. The same code seems to work properly in the Flutter [sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) mentioned in docs. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Here's my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyAppWidget());

class MyAppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppWidget> {
  final _inputKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _messangerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  String inputText = "";

  String appendString() {
    setState(() {
      inputText += inputText;
    });
    return inputText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _messangerKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Assignment"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _inputKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: (inputString) {
                  inputText = inputString;
                  if (inputString.length < 5) {
                    return 'Please enter a longer string';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_inputKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  }
                },
                child: Text("Enter"),
              ),
              Text(appendString())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the exception I am getting

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.

MyAppWidget widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.

Handler: "onTap"

#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:991
#3      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:assignment_1/main.dart:48
#2      ScaffoldMessenger.of
package:flutter/…/material/scaffold.dart:224
#1      debugCheckHasScaffoldMessenger
package:flutter/…/material/debug.dart:153
#0      debugCheckHasScaffoldMessenger.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/debug.dart:142
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Typically, the ScaffoldMessenger widget is introduced by the MaterialApp at the top of your application widget tree.

        renderObject: RenderView#a5074
    [root]
The ancestors of this widget were
    state: _MyAppState#a2cb9
Restarted application in 691ms.

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.

MyAppWidget widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a ScaffoldMessenger ancestor was: MyAppWidget
```

Comment: would you try like this?
scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(mySnackBar);
scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar(mySnackBar);
scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar(mySnackBar);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(mySnackBar); scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar(mySnackBar); scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar(mySnackBar);

Answer (score 21):

## The Issue / Why this happens

To answer the original question: "What am I missing here?":

**`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` is using a `context` not underneath (i.e. not a child of) `MaterialApp`.**  <sub>(And there is no `ScaffoldMessenger` to be found above.)</sub>

Native Flutter static methods `<SomeClassName>.of(context)` walk up the widget tree looking for an `InheritedWidget` type parent named `<SomeClassName>`.  So `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` is looking for a `ScaffoldMessenger` parent.<sup>1</sup>

`MaterialApp` widget provides us a `ScaffoldMessenger` because it wraps its children in a `ScaffoldMessenger`.  Here's an excerpt of `MaterialApp's` "builder" method:

```
  Widget _materialBuilder(BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger( // <<<< <<<< hello Mr. ScaffoldMessenger
      key: widget.scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: AnimatedTheme(
        data: theme,
        child: widget.builder != null
          ? Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return widget.builder!(context, child); // your kid
              },
            )
          : child ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The `child` above is likely your top-most widget that you provided to `MaterialApp`.  Only *that widget's **build method** and below* will find the `ScaffoldMessenger` from `MaterialApp` in its parent ancestry.

The original question's `.showSnackBar()` was looking up `MyApp's` context / parent ancestry, ***not*** `MaterialApp's`.

```
MyApp(context)
 -> MaterialApp(gets MyApp context) + other Widget(gets MyApp context) (no ScaffoldMessenger avail!)
   -> kids (gets MaterialApp context, thus ScaffoldMessenger above)
```

## Code from Original Question

It's really easy to mistake which `context` we're using.

In the original code snippet, we're using the closest visible `context` at this level, which is `MyApp's`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // <<<< this MyApp context...
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _messangerKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Assignment"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _inputKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: (inputString) {
                  inputText = inputString;
                  if (inputString.length < 5) {
                    return 'Please enter a longer string';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_inputKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( // is this context <<<
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  }
```

Even though the `Scaffold > Form > ElevatedButton` widgets appear physically "lower/underneath" `MaterialApp`, they're currently within `MyApp's build(BuildContext context)` method and thus are currently using `MyApp's` `context`.

To use the context of `MaterialApp`, `Scaffold/Form/ElevatedButton` need to be called from inside a `build(BuildContext context)` method that's *inside* `MaterialApp` & thus gets its `context`.

One way to avoid the above pitfall is to keep `MyApp/MaterialApp` very simple and start our coding another level down, say in `HomePage` in the example below:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.bindings}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(), // <<< put your stuff in HomePage's build() method
    );
  }

}
```

Alternatively we can wrap the `home:` widget in a `Builder` widget ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)) and every child within that `Builder` will then be using `MaterialApp's context`, which has the first available `ScaffoldMessenger`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.bindings}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // stuff here gets MaterialApp context
      }),
    );
  }

}
```

And as mentioned in other answers we can use a `scaffoldMessengerKey` arg using a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>` as described in the [migration guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger#migration-guide) when `ScaffoldMessenger` was introduced.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The `InheritedWidget` type looked up by this `.of()` is actually `_ScaffoldMessengerScope`, which contains the `ScaffoldMessengerState` field, which is the object providing the `SnackBar` API methods we're interested in, such as `.showSnackBar()`</sub>

Answer (score 15):

as suggested by [EngineSense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799284/enginesense), Created one Global key

```
final _messangerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
```

and added this in the onPressed method of button

```
_messangerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
```

Here's the updated changes for reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyAppWidget());

class MyAppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppWidget> {
  final _inputKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _messangerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  String inputText = "";

  String appendString() {
    setState(() {
      inputText += inputText;
    });
    return inputText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _messangerKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Assignment"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _inputKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: (inputString) {
                  inputText = inputString;
                  if (inputString.length < 5) {
                    return 'Please enter a longer string';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_inputKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _messangerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  }
                },
                child: Text("Enter"),
              ),
              Text(appendString())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make the SnackBarGlobal a class and make it static so you can use it throughout your application.

This is a small example where you change the navigation in different widgets and in each of them you can fire the SnackBarGlobal. view on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a0416fd6c3f9e3638dd977ddfde944e4)

You can also see the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger#description-of-change) where it explains the error ***Scaffold widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: SnackbarGlobal.key,
      routes: routes,
      initialRoute: 'pageOne',
    );
  }
}

class SnackbarGlobal {
  static GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> key =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  static void show(String message) {
    key.currentState!
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String route;

  MyPage(this.title, this.route);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Go to $route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Show SnackBar in $title'),
              onPressed: () {
                SnackbarGlobal.show('This is a SnackBar in $title');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  'pageOne': (BuildContext context) => MyPage('My Page One', 'pageTwo'),
  'pageTwo': (BuildContext context) => MyPage('My Page Two', 'pageThree'),
  'pageThree': (BuildContext context) => MyPage('My Page Three', 'pageOne'),
};
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer +100 because without making the key global it's kinda useless. And yet no other answers related to ScaffoldMessenger discuss what's needed to use it from _anywhere_, which is, of course, the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue, and found a strange behavior.

Below code is copy from [Display a snackbar](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars), it worked well

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SnackBarDemo());

class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('SnackBar Demo'),
        ),
        body: const SnackBarPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );

          // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
          // and use it to show a SnackBar.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I remove the `SnackBarPage` class, and copy it’s code in `build()` method to the `SnackBarDemo` class directly, something like below.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SnackBarDemo());

class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('SnackBar Demo'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                  content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Undo',
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Some code to undo the change.
                    },
                  ),
                );

                // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
                // and use it to show a SnackBar.
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
              },
              child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Then it will **NOT** work any more, and raise `No ScaffoldMessenger widget found. SnackBarDemo widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.` , It seems that `ScaffoldMessenger` only work when wrapped in some `Widget` class. I don't known why.

Comment: it seems that u shoud get ScaffoldMessenger out of materialApp widget and separate ScaffoldMessenger  in another class widget out of  materialApp widget

Comment: For future travelers, the reason the code doesn't work directly in the build method is because that context is actually one layer above the MaterialApp (which is where the ScaffoldMessenger comes from).  When you wrap that code in another layer, the SnackBarPage, the context is one layer deeper which now includes MaterialApp in the widget tree.

Using `context` within `MaterialApp` can see from SnackBarDemo up.
Using `context` within `SnackBarPage` can see from `MaterialApp` and above which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter gallery on GitHub shows that the feature is going to get an upgrade and it will be updated when they merge their flutter master branch again with the updated one. For now, you can use Scaffold only or implement it as a key after writing manual code for it in a key variable.

Comment: Hi! Could you add link to github issue?

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to have a seperated **StatefulWidget**  for The **Scaffold()** (as below **MyScaffold**). Its working with me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyAppWidget());

class MyAppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyScaffold());
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyScaffoldState createState() => _MyScaffoldState();
}

class _MyScaffoldState extends State<MyScaffold> {
  String inputText = "";

  String appendString() {
    setState(() {
      inputText += inputText;
    });
    return inputText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Assignment"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              validator: (inputString) {
                inputText = inputString!;
                if (inputString.length < 5) {
                  return 'Please enter a longer string';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
              },
              child: Text("Enter"),
            ),
            Text(appendString())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my first answer so i don't know a lot about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution is to put the scaffold in a separate widget and have the snackbar inside the scaffold as below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: HomePage()
);
}
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 const HomePage({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("My App"),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Snackbar')
                )
            );
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

Use This:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: _content ,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),));
```

Answer (score -1):

just use the onpress under a builder widget and pass the builder context to scaffoldmessenger.